# Is there any way to pass an unquoted expression as an argument to a python function and be able to work with that argument inside the function?

Tags: python, function, arguments, expression

This may sound like a strange request, but purely for aesthetic reasons, I would like to do what I asked for in the title.

Here's why.

I've written a function using the machinery in matplotlib, which we'll call function_plot, that will plot functions supplied as arguments. For example the following

```
function_plot('sin(x)', -10, 10)`
```

will make a plot of sin(x) from x = -10 to x = 10.

function_plot works perfectly. The only problem is that my mathematical friends would perfer to be able to pass sin(x) to it without quotes.

I've tried to rewrite function_plot in various ways to eliminate the quotes but nothing I tried works.

One approach that I thought was hopeful was to pass sin(x), or just sin, without quotes, capture the expression inside of function_plot, put quotes around it and then proceed in the original way. That's the genesis of my request.

But whenever an unquoted expression is passed to a function, if the expression is not something already defined, a "name not known" error results.

So is there any way to do what I would like to do, or should just give up?

Comment: Passing a function as an argument to another function is quite common in *Python*. You can define `def function_plot(func, lo_val, hi_val):`, and call it like: `function_plot(sin, -10, 10)`.

Comment: Are your friends writing Python code, or is your code taking string input from them (via `input` or file)?  If they are writing code, then they need to get used to quoting strings.  Regardless of how you input it, Python will try to evaluate `sin(x)`, succeeding if `sin` and `x` are defined, otherwise raising an error.

Comment: How are you computing the points? If it's as simple as evaluating the expression at specific inputs, then a lambda would suffice.

Comment: @hpaulj My friends are mathematicians, not programmers, who want a free plotting function that resembles the interface that Mathematica uses, but don't want to pay $3000 for Mathematica.

Comment: @Lamda Fairy  Yes i"m evaluating the expression at various points along the domain. I've been doing Python for about 6 months and have not yet explored lamdas. This is probably a good motivation for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lambda` expressions to construct the function inline. For example:

```
function_plot(lambda x: sin(x/2) + 1, -10, 10)
```

Then, in the definition of `function_plot`, you can call this function for each value in the domain:

```
def function_plot(f, low, high):
    points = [(x, f(x)) for x in range(low, high+1)]
    # Do something with the points
```